# Self-Closing tags - An anti pattern?

Tags: html, web, tags

Often when I read tutorials or books, I see stuff like this:

```
<i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-down cart-item__modify"></i>
```

Instead of "self closing tags", e.g. `<i .... />` they close the those empty tags with an explicit `</i>`. Why? Is this somehow considered bad or not very readable?

Comment: Self-closing tags are an XMLism. They mean nothing in text/html. The HTML parsers that web browsers use don’t actually recognize them as self-closing. And in the specific case of the HTML `i` element, the `</i>` end tag is always required. Otherwise an HTML parser will treat everything after that `<i .... />` as child content of that `i` element.

Comment: See https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-i-element. For every element in the HTML spec, the spec contains a *Tag omission in text/html* section that states whether the start tag or end tag is omissible. If an end tag is omissible, you can put a slash at the end of the start tag — e.g., `<p />` — but that’s pointless because to an HTML parser `<p>` and `<p />` get parsed exactly the same.